# AngularJS open window when click in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am building a website with different markers shown in a Google Maps map and a search engine. I can navigate through the map with the markers, I can click on a marker to show the content. When I click on a search results, the map pan to the result and I would like at the same time that the windows with markers content to be opened.
This is my code

mymarkers.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
app.constant("myMarkers", [{
                lat: .., 
                lng: .., 
                title:'..'
},{
                lat: .., 
                lng: .., 
                title:'..'
}..]
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
angular.module('myApp').controller("myController", ["$scope", "myMarkers", function($scope, myMarkers){
    $scope.markers= myMarkers; 
    $scope.$on("gmaps.marker.click", function(event, map, marker) {

    });
    //call the directive with the Angular event system
    //1st parameter of the listener = event
    $scope.centerMapOnMarker = function (marker){
        $scope.$broadcast('center-on-marker', marker);
    }
}]);

app.directive('myMap', ["myMarkers", function(myMarkers) {
    // directive link function
    var link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var map, infoWindow;
        var markers = [];
        var mapOptions = {..
        };

        // init the map
        function initMap() {..
        }    

        // place a marker
        function setMarker(map, position, title, content,link) {..
           ..
        }
        //center to the marker   
        //1st parameter of the listener = event
        scope.$on('center-on-marker', function (event, args) {
            var center = new google.maps.LatLng(args.lat, args.lng);
            map.panTo(center);
            map.setZoom(15);
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); <-- not working
            infowindow.setContent(args.content);
            infowindow.open(map, args);

        });
        function returnMarker(){
           window.alert(markers[0].title);
        }
        // show the map and place some markers
        initMap();

        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            setMarker(map, new google.maps.LatLng(myMarkers[i].lat, myMarkers[i].lng), myMarkers[i].title, myMarkers[i].content, myMarkers[i].icon);
        }

    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<div id="gmaps"></div>',
        replace: true,
        link: link
    };
}]);
```

index.html

```
        <div my-map=""></div>

        <div class="myresearch">
            <input placeholder="Search a restaurant" ng-model="search">
                <div ng-show="search.length">
                <ul class="list" ng-repeat="marker in markers | filter: search as filtered"> 
                    <li>
                    <span ng-click="centerMapOnMarker(marker)">
                    <label class="textr"> {{marker.title}}  </label> 
</li>
</ul>
```

You can see with the arrow which function I would like to add in order to open the window when I click on the search results at the same time that the map move.
Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

It occurs since `InfoWindow.open` function expects [`Marker object`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) as the second argument, but in your example `args` object is *not* a `Marker` class. You could pass instead the *index of selected object*:

```
<span ng-click="centerMapOnMarker($index)" />

$scope.centerMapOnMarker = function(index) {
    $scope.$broadcast('center-on-marker', index);
}
```

and then get the corresponding  marker object:

```
scope.$on('center-on-marker', function(event, index) {
   var selectedMarker = markers[index];
   map.panTo(selectedMarker.getPosition());
   map.setZoom(15);
   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); 
   infowindow.setContent(selectedMarker.content);
   infowindow.open(map, selectedMarker);
});
```

[**Demo (plunker)**](https://plnkr.co/edit/mC2qIpcTTNSjEgQpNY2S?p=preview)

Comment: Don't know why but the window opened is empty (without the proper content) and it doesn't pan to the right marker .. Altough I don't have any error

Comment: Have you seen the example i have provided (plunker link)?, it demonstrates how to set info window content and position it over marker

Comment: I post it as an answer

Comment: Yes, thank you very much Vadim but I have got the same issue in your plunker link. Le Rivage is misunderstood with the Chilis Restaurant Lunch